# Removing 4 digits from column with character

Tags: sql

Right now I have a data like this in my column:

`mustang 2004\ford 2005`

I need to remove the year 2004 and 2005. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which version of SQL (SQL Server, mySQL, Oracle)?

Comment: which database are you using? can you provide a sample of your data? I would rather suggest you to use a `substr` function but from what you write I'm not able to know how much you know about SQL

Comment: what is the structure of your table?

Comment: Do you need to remove the year values in the column of all rows in the table?

Comment: yes  since its not showing as a year its just a number

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()`:

```
select replace(replace(col, '2004', ''), '2005', '')
```

If this doesn't answer your question, you should edit our question and provide more details about what you really need.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this would be with two calls

You will need to replace the TABLENAME and COLUMNNAME with the appropriate names for your table

```
Update TABLENAME 
Set COLUMNNAME = replace(COLUMNNAME, '2004', '');

Update TABLENAME 
Set COLUMNNAME = replace(COLUMNNAME, '2005', '');
```